# Could this be re-written without the union operator?

Tags: sql

Consider this DB at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all
The goal is to write a query to list all the cities in that DB.
Can the query below be re-written without using the union operator? in ANSI SQL or any other ones. I just want to get a general idea. Thank you

```
SELECT City, country FROM Customers
UNION
SELECT City, country FROM Suppliers
order by city, country
```

Comment: Pick *a* database system and add *that* tag back please. Don't tag irrelevant products.

Answer (score 0):

The only other way (I can think of) to do it is with a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       COALESCE(c.City, s.City) AS City,
       COALESCE(c.country, s.country) AS country
FROM Customers c FULL JOIN Suppliers s
ON s.City = c.City AND s.country = c.country
```

Note that `UNION` is the correct method for this requirement and that `FULL OUTER JOIN` is not supported by databases like MySql and SQLite.

Comment: i think it is cheating as you UNION a LEFT and RIGHT JOIN to get all values

Comment: @nbk this is the definition (sort of) for the full outer join.

Comment: @forpas what if we use IN operator?

Comment: @WaterfrVilla I don't see how `IN` would help here.

Comment: @forpas in ( A) or in (B)

Comment: @WaterfrVilla what is A and B?